# Print using shared printer in JsPrintSetup

Tags: firefox

I am using firefox jsPrintSetup extension to print a iframe silently. It works well when the printer is directly connected to the PC. When I tried to print it on a shared printer am getting an error 'Selected printer is not available'.

How can I specify an shared printer in jsPrintSetup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally this worked!

1. Made the shared printer as default printer in the system
2. Get the list of printers connected to the system using js
3. Pass the first value of the response array to the jsPrintSetup printer function